# Eve Online - what is the mix of NPC damage types?

Tags: eve-online

There are four types of damage in Eve (kinetic, explosive, thermal, EM), and the last time I extensively played the game, most NPCs only used one or two types of damage (with only a few tough ones using all four). So you generally only needed to boost your ship's resistance to a couple of types for a given mission.

However, it's been a while since I played, and there have been a *lot* of changes to the game. So I'm wondering how the NPCs have changed - are they still mostly using two damage types (and the same each time), so it's worth looking it up and planning for? Or do they use all types, and/or change what type they use, so you have to be prepared for anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [list](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/EM) of damage types that tend to be used by different NPC factions on the EvE wiki.  It also lists which damage types tend to be most effective against them.

### NPC damage Types

The various factions and pirates across New Eden tend to inflict particular damage types over others. The following is a list of the damage types inflicted by different factions

#### Damage done by NPCs

- Angel Cartel: All types, although mostly kinetic and explosive.
- Amarr Navy: EM and thermal.
- Ammatar Navy: EM and thermal.
- Blood Raiders: EM and thermal.
- Caldari Navy: Kinetic and thermal.
- Centii: EM and thermal.
- Coreli: Kinetic and thermal.
- Corpii: EM and thermal.
- Domination: All types, mostly kinetic and explosive.
- Gallente Navy: Kinetic and thermal.
- Gist: All types, mostly kinetic and explosive.
- Guristas: Kinetic and thermal.
- Khanid: EM and thermal.
- Mercenary: All types.
- Mordu's Legion: Kinetic and thermal.
- Odamian: Kinetic and thermal.
- Pith: Kinetic and thermal.
- Rogue Drones: All types.
- Republic fleet: All types, mostly kinetic and explosive.
- Sansha: EM and thermal.
- Serpentis: Kinetic and thermal.

#### Best damage to do to NPCs

- Guristas - Kinetic
- Serpentis - Thermal or Kinetic
- Mordu's Legion - Thermal or Kinetic
- Blood Raiders - EM or Thermal
- Sansha - EM or Thermal
- Angel Cartel - Explosive
- Mercenary - Thermal

Comment: A link is fine, thanks - but how up-to-date is it likely to be? I don't see any timestamps on it.

Comment: It's the "official" wiki and the last edits on that article are less than a month old, so I think it should be a solid source.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the missions DB at [eve-info](http://eveinfo.com/missions/) to be the most helpful source for damage types.  Some of the data is stale, but users often post updated info in the comments.  Even with stale data, this is a very useful place to find out exactly which resistances you should use in a specific mission.

Answer (score 1):

There have been a lot of changes in the game during its lifespan, but NPC damage hasn't ever changed.  There have been new NPC combatants added to the game, but the existing ones are the same today as they were the day they were introduced.

Well, AFAIK anyway!  8 )